# How do you clear a password field in Scala Swing

Tags: scala-swing

I can't figure out how to clear a scala.swing.PasswordField. I have tried setting the text(String) method to an empty String...

```
passwordField.text = ""
```

but it didn't work. It works on a TextField, but not on a PasswordField. I also can not set a new value using the password method...

```
passwordField.password = "" // not allowed
```

Any ideas...?

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved the problem using 'peer'.

```
passwordField.peer.setText("")
```